# How to change the organization name on an existing Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I created a once off Xcode project but entered the organisation name in incorrectly. How can I change it?

Answer (score 63):

There are two things you will need to do. With the project or target selected, you can update the "Organization" field in the "Project Document" section of the "Utilities" panel (usually on the right).

Next, for an existing source files, you will need to perform a search/replace to update the header comments. Only new files will automatically get the new organization name.

Answer (score 41):

Click on target -> click show the file inspector -> organization name text field  edit organization name

[image]

If you need to edit Project name

1- select you'r project then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> edit name

2- show rename project content items

[image]

3- click rename

4- build your project

> Note : If you use pod should change Target name in podfile then `pod
>   install` ، You will find that he has created a new file
>   `newTarget.xcworkspace`